# CygWin: MD5 sum did not match, exiting

Tags: cygwin

`cyg-get install lzop` gave:

```
MD5 sum did not match, exiting
```

I tried:

```
cyg-get update
rm /setup/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.kernel.org%2fsourceware%2fcygwin/release/lzop/lzop-1.03-1.tar.bz2
```

That did not help.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Try a different mirror?

Comment: I would suggest removing this question, as it holds little value to others. You basically said you needed to update a package for something to work, which is a common troubleshooting step.

Comment: @HunterStevens - I believe the OP is attempting to update a package, but that process failed.  The OP is now asking for advice on getting this process to work.

Comment: My comment is also in reference to the fact that OP provided such a simple answer to his question. He provides few details to make it reproducible or helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading `cyg-get` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt-cyg update` to update Cygwin.